# Categories Tag inside of Channel Entries Tag understanding problem

Tags: channel-entries, categories, entries, category-name

I use this code to list and filter my 3000 blog entries by category.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog" limit="200" disable="member_data|pagination|category_fields" category="1&2" dynamic="no" parse="inward"}
           {title}
           {categories show_group="2"}
                {category_name}
           {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I get 140 entries but only 10 entries with category_name.
Why stop this after 10 entries?

**Update**

When i disable Transcribe it works fine.
Its a Transcribe problem/bug.

It works with Transcribe when i set the limit to 3000.
But it´s increase the Total Execution Time to 3sec....

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Can try the category parameter like category="1|2".